# I am getting this error on obj.contentdocumentid ='Value'. Please help

Tags: trigger

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient
>   access rights on cross-reference id: []

Comment: can you please provide some more details?

Comment: Pls check if the running user has create or edit permission on the object concerned

Comment: can you show your trigger code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the Id specified isn't valid for that user. Either it belongs to another org, the user doesn't have read access to the record, or the record was deleted.

This usually occurs when using hard coded Id values, or when querying records in system mode and trying to link the record. Make sure you're querying the record for its Id, and that the user has access to the record.

Answer (score 0):

It can be because of the following reasons:

1. contentdocumentid is doesn't follow the right 18 digit Id format
2. contentdocumentid is in 18 digit format but belongs to different object or it is deleted (first three digits in Id field will help you identify the object type)
3. User might not have access to that object

I highly doubt the second case